# Problem using OLD variable in after update trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I just want to know can I use the OLD keyword to retrieve the older value after updated. I am using this in After update trigger and I am not able to get the old value but new is working. Database being used is MYSQL. I have read in forums and some people are saying old will work and some are opposing that. Please clarify.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the previous value, you should use a *before* trigger instead of an *after* trigger.

> The trigger time is at what stage during the process takes place. This can be either BEFORE or AFTER. If using before this means that the trigger code will be able to work with both the values currently stored in there original state and the new values

[MySQL Triggers : Trigger time](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Trigger_Time)